# How can i make routing on this route path?

Tags: angular

I have this route path.
sport/:sport_id/prediction/create

I know that i we want to route to
sport/:sport_id for example it would be

```
<a [routerLink]="['/sport', sportId]">
```

but how can i include prediction and create after the sportId route parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add it to the array like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/sport', sportId, 'prediction', 'create']">
```